# Group by more combinations

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have the following table to represent a conversation between users.

```
message | user1 | user2 | unixtime
msg1    | 14    | 21    | -
msg2    | 21    | 12    | -
msg1    | 14    | 18    | -
msg3    | 14    | 21    | -
msg2    | 18    | 14    | -
msg4    | 21    | 12    | -
```

I want to show a list of a a specific user's conversations by selecting all messages with current_user = user1 or user2.
So far this SELECT will select the correct messages but the grouping doesn't work correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE user1 = '".$_SESSION['login']['ID']."'
    OR user2 = '".$_SESSION['login']['ID']."'
    ORDER BY unixtime DESC
) as list
GROUP BY user1, user2
ORDER BY unixtime DESC
```

It will only group the messages with the same user1 and user2 and not if the two users are reversed. 
Is this done by a more advanced grouping or should I join the table in some way?

Comment: you can group by LEAST(user1, user2), GREATEST(user1, user2) but what are you trying to do? you are selecting all columns * and grouping by just two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you want the query to do, because you are using `group by` and `select *`.  The `select *` returns indeterminate values from matching rows.  I don't know why anyone would want to do this.  You can read about this in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

If you want to counts the messages:

```
SELECT least(user1, user2), greatest(user1, user2), count(*)
FROM messages
WHERE '".$_SESSION['login']['ID']."' in (user1, user2)
GROUP BY least(user1, user2), greatest(user1, user2)
```

Comment: Adding least(user1, user2), greatest(user1, user2) to my GROUP BY did the job - thanks! I want to show all the messages, thats why * but maybe I should revisit that